# Calculate Percentage Overtime in SSRS 2012

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am trying create a report that calcualtes the Overtime someone has worked in a week, my understanding of the calulation would be.

My Columns are :

Extra Hours Worked Per Week

Total Hour Worked Per Week

Calculation

Extra Hours Worked Per Week / (Extra Hours Worked Per Week + Total Hour Worked Per Week) * 100

If I represent All the columns as minutes sum them up and do the calculation I get one figure but if I sum up all the minutes in to hours and minutes and do the same calculation I get a different figure.  What I want to know is, is the Calculation correct and if so, should I be doing the calculation just using minutes or using hours and minutes.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to calculate the percentage of Extra hours, your calculation should be:

`((TotalHours * 100)/(TotalHours - ExtraHours))-100`

And my advise to you is to keep the calculation in minutes, and in the end convert it to hours (and minutes).

Comment: Hi Gil, thats looking like it makes sense, can I just check that my understanding is right with an example Bob works 8.15 minutes 5 days a week so that is 495 minutes per day, he works an extra 30 minutes per day unpaid over time so the calculation would be (2475 * 100) / (2475 - 150) I am trying to caluclate as a percentage how much extra none paid work he does each week, my figures doesn't look right though!

Comment: That current, the answer is 106.45% (this is the effort that Bob worked this week),To be more clear: if he would work only the exact time that he have to work - the answer will be 100%)

Comment: Hi Gil,  thanks again for the comprehensive response and that was the answer I was getting.  Could this also be written as 6.45% over what he was contracted to do and if so, is it possible to show it as this rather than 106.45%

Comment: Thanks again for all the excellent help Gil, its very much appreciated.